# Weird sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Supply the missing number in the following sequence:

```
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 24, ___, 100, 121, 10.000.
```

I've spent like 1,5 hours on this weird sequence, but still haven't worked out complete algorithm of n-th element of this sequence. Any ideas?

Comment: [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing number is $31$ and this sequence is the [the following](http://oeis.org/A008713), base 16-n where $n$ is the index.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!

Comment: Mark it as an answer if this meets your criteria.

Comment: Apparently, "base $16-n$", not base-n.

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thanks!